# Probability and limits

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $X$ be a real random variable associated with a probabilistic space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) $ and such that $X(\omega) \in\mathbb{R} $ for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Let $\{\alpha_n\} $ be a sequence of real numbers such that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \alpha_n = \infty$.

Then $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} (X \geq \alpha_{n}) =0$.

Is it true?

Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course. You can suppose WLOG that $\alpha _n$ is increasing. Since $\{X\geq \alpha _{n+1}\}\subset \{X\geq \alpha _n\}$, using continuity of the probability gives
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P\{X\geq \alpha _n\}=\mathbb P\{X=\infty \}=0.$$

So, even if $X\in\mathbb R$ a.s. instead of $X(\omega )\in \mathbb R$ for all $\omega $, it still be true.